# iOS Bluetooth LE cant get notification programatically but can in other apps

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to get my iOS program to communicate with a custom Bluetooth LE device. I can connect to it, read all the services, and read all the `CBCharacteristic` objects for each service.

I am trying to get notified when one specific `CBCharacteristic` is updated. The `CBCharacteristic.properties` is set to 0x10 (Notify) but the `CBCharacteristic.isNotifying` is false.

After calling the following line of code:

```
myDevice.peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: myChar)
```

I am expecting to receive notifications via the `CBPeripheralDelegate` function:

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {}
```

but it never gets called.

In addition, using the [LightBlue Explorer app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) from [PunchThrough.com](http://punchthrough.com/) I CAN get notifications, so I know it is possible. What is the LightBlue app doing that I am not?

Has anyone seen something similar to this?

For reference, the device uses [WLT2564M](http://www.wi-linktech.com/index.php?pagename=product_detail&id=18) Bluetooth module. Also I can read the value using

```
myDevice.peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(myChar)
```

without any issues.

Comment: How is `myChar` stored?  Is it a property or a local variable?

Comment: Property: It is local to the ViewController and persists as long as the VC does. I can read the value using myDevice.peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(myChar)  no problem.

Comment: I suppose the the same applies to the peripheral, and that you connected to it (and weren't disconnected in the meantime)? I also suppose you did correctly set the delegate for it? Anything showing up in the logs? Did you implement `peripheral:didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:error:`? Any error there?

Comment: @jcaron that was it. I left this code in the middle and just got back to it a few months later. Didn't realize I had not set the delegate yet. Please post an answer and I will mark correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to check:

- the `peripheral` property needs to persist for the duration of its use
- you must have connected to it (and weren't disconnected in the meantime)
- check that the `delegate` is properly set
- check logs
- make sure you implement `peripheral:didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:error:` and log any errors there